# patch kubernetes cronjob with kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob, kustomize

I am trying to patch a cronjob, but somehow it doesn't work as I would expect. I use the same folder structure for a deployment and that works.

This is the folder structure:

```sh
.
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── war.cron.yaml
└── overlays
    └── staging
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        ├── war.cron.patch.yaml
        └── war.cron.staging.env
```

base/kustomization.yaml

```yaml
---
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- war.cron.yaml
```

base/war.cron.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: war-event-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: war-event-cron
            image: my-registry/war-service
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - python
            - run.py
            args:
            - sync-events
            envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: war-event-cron-secret
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Then I am trying to patch this in the staging overlay.

overlays/staging/kustomization.yaml

```yaml
---
kind: Kustomization
namespace: staging
bases:
- "../../base"
patchesStrategicMerge:
- war.cron.patch.yaml
secretGenerator:
- name: war-event-cron-secret
  behavior: create
  envs:
  - war.cron.staging.env
```

overlays/staging/war.cron.patch.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: war-event-cron
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: war-event-cron
            image: my-registry/war-service:nightly
            args:
            - sync-events
            - --debug
```

But the result of `kustomize build overlays/staging/` is not what I want. The `command` is gone and the `secret` is not referenced.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ...
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: war-event-cron-secret-d8m6bh7284
  namespace: staging
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: war-event-cron
  namespace: staging
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
            - sync-events
            - --debug
            image: my-registry/war-service:nightly
            name: war-event-cron
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: '*/5 * * * *'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's known bug in `kustomize` - check and follow [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4062) topic (created ~ one month ago) on GitHub for more information.

For now, fix for your issue is to use `apiVersion:batch/v1beta1` instead of `apiVersion: batch/v1` in `base/war.cron.yaml` and `overlays/staging/war.cron.patch.yaml` files.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I ended up using json patch.

Comment: is that still the case? It doesn't work for me but maybe there's already a better workaround?